# How to concat to Javascript float number from dot?

Tags: javascript

Here float number:249.123

So desired value should be :249123;

I tried parseInt but it didn't work.

```
var myNumber=parseInt(249.123);
console.log(myNumber):

>249
```

So how can we concat float nuber without throw from dot?

Comment: Because of floating point imprecision, you cannot do this accurately.

Comment: You can do a trick. Change this number to string split by dot and join.

Comment: @CzłowiekFinŚpiewak or simply replace the dot with an empty string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it a string, remove the dot, and then turn it back into a number:

```
Number(249.123.toString().replace('.',''))
```

Comment: Also pass radix or Use Number()